# How can I connect to a Rails SSE streaming page in an Android application (Java)?

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events, event-stream

I have a rails route set up in my backend that uses `ActionController::Live` to stream server-sent events (HTML5 SSE, content-type data/event-stream). Ideally, I would like to interface directly with this route in my Android frontend using some Java library for dealing with server-sent events. However, I can't seem to find anything other than Java-backend (J2EE) libraries for SSE. My question is twofold: does there exist a Java/Android SSE client library, and if not, is there a simpler method that SSEs ultimately abstract to (like, are they just a glorified form of websocket or something of the like) such that I could use another type of library or normal Android networking?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the library
 for instances are [jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#d0e10373) and [okhttp-sse](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-sse)